# How to make a toggle button in a commandbar VBA PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to make a toggle button on a command bar but I'm coming across two problems 1) It keeps performing 'removebleed' rather than toggling between the two. 2) it doesn't show the button being toggled. First I've attached the menu button code then after the code for the button. Many thanks for any help, Jay

```
Set ToggleButton = oToolbar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)

    With ToggleButton

         .DescriptionText = "Switch bleed on or off"

         .Caption = "Bleed on/off"

         .OnAction = "ToggleButton"

         .Style = msoButtonCaption

    End With
```

```
Sub ToggleButton()

Static Toggle As Boolean
If Toggle = True Then
With Application.CommandBars.ActionControl
 .State = Not .State
End With
 Toggle = False ' changes the variable so next time it unpresses the button and runs the other macro

AddBleed

Else

RemoveBleed

End If

End Sub

Sub AddBleed()
Dim WidthBleed As String
Dim HeightBleed As String

WidthBleed = 0.125 * 72
HeightBleed = 0.25 * 72

SWidth = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
SHeight = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight

With Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup

    .SlideWidth = SWidth + WidthBleed

    .SlideHeight = SHeight + HeightBleed

End With

End Sub

Sub RemoveBleed()
Dim WidthBleed As String
Dim HeightBleed As String
Dim SWidth As String
Dim SHeight As String

WidthBleed = 0.125 * 72
HeightBleed = 0.25 * 72

SWidth = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth
SHeight = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight

With Application.ActivePresentation.PageSetup

    .SlideWidth = SWidth - WidthBleed

    .SlideHeight = SHeight - HeightBleed

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Command bars are obsolete, they were used in Office 2003. The VBA is retained for backward compatibility. Old macros that create command bars will have the controls re-routed to the Add-ins tab in PowerPoint instead of displaying as a true command bar. Instead, look into modifying the RibbonUI.Here's an introductory article from the Microsoft web site: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/customize-the-office-fluent-ribbon-by-using-an-open-xml-formats-file. Here's a RibbonUI editor, this makes the job easier: https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the Toggle True to the 'Else' side

```
Sub ToggleButton()

Static Toggle As Boolean
If Toggle = True Then
With Application.CommandBars.ActionControl
 .State = Not .State
End With
 Toggle = False ' changes the variable so next time it unpresses the button and runs the other macro

RemoveBleed

Else

With Application.CommandBars.ActionControl 'unpresses the button
 .State = Not .State
End With
 Toggle = True 'changes the variable so next time it operates the other macro


AddBleed

End If

End Sub
```